# Hyde static page site generator - issue with running hyde command from command line

Tags: python, pip, hyde

I installed Hyde with pip. I can see hyde in /usr/local/share/python. But when I am running hyde from command line, I am getting "Bash - Command not found error".

I am on Mac OSX (ML) and python 2.7.3

Please help.

Comment: What do you see when you type `echo $PATH`? You need to make sure `/usr/local/share` is in the path.

Comment: I have /usr/local/share in my PATH. But still getting same error.

Comment: Got the answer now, I need to have /usr/local/share/python in my path and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I need to have /usr/local/share/python in my PATH.